# JavaScript/HTML inconsistent display of checkbox inner HTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

On Firefox 54, the first and the third checkbox show their inner text while the second does not but they all have the same structure, just constructed using different methods. What is the reason for this behaviour?

```js
input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
input2.innerHTML = "Check me inner HTML";
input2.innerText = "Check me inner Text";

input3 = document.createRange().createContextualFragment("<input type='checkbox'>Check me fragment</input>");
document.body.appendChild(input3);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">Check me HTML</input>
<input type="checkbox" id="input2"></input>
```

Comment: Browsers are allowed to handle invalid HTML as they wish, there's no rules. [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) is an empty element, it "_Must have a start tag and must not have an end tag_".

Comment: `<input>` is a void element and doesn't even have closing tag

Comment: HTML [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) elements are empty elements and must not have an end tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input>` elements do not have an "inner HTML". The resulting HTML structure is:

```
<input type="checkbox">Check me HTML
<input type="checkbox" id="input2">Check me inner Text</input>
<script type="text/javascript">/* your js */</script>
<input type="checkbox">Check me fragment
```

The second one isn't valid HTML. The "inner" text won't be rendered.

I'm not quite sure why the 3rd one renders properly. The browser might be able to fix the fragment before it's included in the page.
(The `</input>` may just be getting stripped, making the HTML valid)